# Loop within 26 numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a number: 20. I want to be able to add 10 to it and get 4.
This is supposed to be looping the alphabet (numbers instead of letters)
Eg.

Start with 20
(adding 10)

```
21
22
23
24
25
26
(again from 1)
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework question ... What have you tried so far? What happened?

Comment: Another option besides the obvious modulo solution: [`itertools.cycle(range(1, 27))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

Comment: @Isogen74 Not homework, I'm trying to make Casear Chiper encryption, but I want it to be able to support any number of cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you should go with the modulo operator (`%`) which gives you the reminder from a division.

```
>>> i = 20
>>> i = (i + 10) % 26
>>> print(i)
4
```

You could even create some kind of function for this:

```
>>> def add_and_modulo(i, addition, modulo=26):
...     return (i + addition) % modulo
...
>>> i = 20
>>> i = add_and_modulo(i, 10)
>>> print(i)
4
```

Although it's just one line of code, two calculations, so you're often better off just not writing a custom function, unless you use it a lot.